# Twitter API / Tweepy: Retrieve tweets by author id and date/timestamp

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets, twitterapi-python

I scraped millions of tweets with the Twitter API V2 and in order to publish the data I wanted to replace all data with the tweet id, so that future users can reproduce my dataset.
However I just realized that I did not save the "tweet_id" and I am now looking for ways to retrieve a tweet with different informations. I thought it would be possible to retrieve a tweet if you have the "author_id" and the exact timestamp.

Does anyone know a way how this is possible?
Here is what I have at the moment:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
u = client.get_user(id=1241497988423454720)
print(u)
print(u.data.username)
```

This gets me the username. However I don't know how to get a tweet at a specific time now.
My dataset looks as follows:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:
It appears as though the twitter API supports fetching a user's (last 3200?) tweets by their user ID [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets), which you could possible use to fetch all tweets by a user. You could probably figure out the original ID of the tweet from there.